# Magento: calling createPost method of AccountController of Customer Module, tries to save customer twice

Tags: magento

In Magento 1.7 community edition, I have overridden the AccountController of the Customer Module.  I have modified the createPost method so that it saves the customer name, email and password only, and returns JSON output so that I an call it using ajax.

To test that the controller is working correctly, I request the method directly, i.e.:

*www.mysite.com.au/customer/account/createpost/?firstname=john&lastname=smithemail=john.smith@mydomain.com&password=xxxxxx&confirmation=xxxxxx*

The issue I am having is that `$customer->save()` is called, an exception is thrown 
(`Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS`), the message being "customer email already exists" which is traced back to `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php`.  The customer record IS inserted despite the exception.

So Magento is attempting to save the customer twice. If I out a return at the top of the  `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer:_beforeSave(Varien_Object $customer)` method, TWO customer records are added.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I realised that this is an issue with PHP running on my Windows 7 PC (I installed the BitNami WAMP stack). I copied the code to a linux box, and the fault is not occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you call `parent::createPostAction();` in new `createPostAction()` method which save customer second time.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Nikolaev.  When I said I had overridden the AccountController, I meant that I copied it to the code/local directory such that it is called instead of the original controller.  So I am not actually extending it.  There is not parent::createPostAction() call.